# what files in django are not necessary for using only templates?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, templates, django-templates

I use django templates 1.2 in my GAE app. I remember default templates in GAE were some kind of old version (0.96 or smth) and I moved to the new one.

The question is - what files and directories I can delete from django folder to minimize its size - I need only templates.

Comment: If you're only going to use templates you're better off using a stand-alone templating library. [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) is similar to Django's Template engine and its super fast!